# stripline between 2 Java GeneralPath

Tags: java, geometry, computational-geometry

Can anyone give me a hint or help me with my following ( hopefully also interesting :-) ) problem.

I have 2 GeneralPath in my JavaProgramm and I would like to findout the stripline between them.

Following situation:

I have 2 GeneralPath A & B

A is a yellow triangle with 3 points ( moveto, lineto, lineto , close )

B (red) was a triangle and is a result of a substraction B-A:

```
B = new Area(gp_B); // General path B area object
A = new Area(gp_A); // General path A area object
B.subtract(A);
```

B has 4 points after the substraction. So there is no intersection between A & B and GeneralPath anymore and A doesn't have any points 
that matches any points of GeneralPath B.

[image]

How can I findout the stripline between them ?

My example is simplified for better explaining. My GeneralPath A & B could also contain Beziercurves with Cubeto:

[image]

Regards
Andreas

Comment: how do you define strip line. is that your invention?  consider more complex examples, where the stripl line is a polygon, ltherwise you would find a soulution which works only in the simplest case

Comment: Stripline is only a word to explain the situation here. English is not my motherlanguage, sorry. Yes the stripline could also be a polygone, because the GeneralPath could also have Beziercurve segments with cubeto.

Answer (score 0):

i doubt that you would get an desired answer, so i first give you some tipps to limit the complexity of your task:

i would reduce your task to so called simple polygons. That are non self intersecting polygons. once that works you may try to extend to bezier paths.
To do your task for a generall path, this is very demaning (is this a master thesis where you have 6 months time for your job, or a CAD system with a customer willing to pay?)

If you still want to do that:
start hand drawing the most complex scenarios: fully overlapping (like a wooden cross).

Then who does the subtraction? is that ready working? which limitations the subtraction has (simple polygons vs non simple)

**One possibility**:

get the source code of the subtraction, try to understand, and extend that part that does the cutting, such that it returns an additional stripe path.

**The other solution:**

A1: compare old objects with the points after cutting. Determine the new introduced points. follow one point on the path until an old point is reached. do that in the other direction, too. concat both directions.

do that for all new points, and finally you get a list of stripes, probably you have to clean up by removinh duplicate lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Your Question : "Then who does the subtraction? is that ready working?" -> subtract is a simple base jawa.awt.geom.area method and yes this works perfect.

Comment: I don't know if I understood solution A1 correct. I guess this will not work, because A doesn't have any points that matches any points of GeneralPath B. See screenshot with different colored points. Thank you anyway.

Comment: i think it will work: triangle B has lost his tip in the subtraction operation, therefore it got (two) new points. these two points must be on the border to A because they are a result of the subztaction. Any new introduced point was added in the subtract operation, and therefore is part of such a stripe (or better common border path)

Comment: Hi Alex. Thank you very much for your help. You are absolutely right regarding the first example. I attached a complexer one. I thought it could be managed with a combination of shape-operations. And yes "common border path" describes it better.

Comment: I first thought you are right, but my A1 algo still works: In Potatoe PathB there was a new Path/Points introduced: the differnce operation removed the oval and added the commomn border to Poly B. All these points are new now. To make this clear, draw only Poly B. Then you see the new points.

Comment: Hi Alex. I am not sure if I have really understood. The only thing I understand is Potatoe :-) I guess "Kartoffel oder Härdöpfel" you understand as well. I do not have the old red potatoe before the subtract. I intersected this for my example and the intersected situation is my only source. Beside I did not understand so far, is this still possible with your method ? My Problem : The common border in my example has 3 points, but 2 in red and 1 in yellow.  Sorry for my lack of understanding and I hope we will keep in contact with this. best regards

Comment: after subtraction can you draw B alone? if yes then B has new points, which you can find